# SQL Update to Linked Server Table fires trigger for each row effected

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm looking at some strange behaviour with a linked database server. I'm simply creating a temporary table variable, adding in some keys which can be found in the linked server table and using it to join with target table for the update.

```
declare  @stats_table table
(
    [Index]     [bigint]            not null primary key
)

insert into @stats_table ([Index] )
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4

update  [source]
set     [source].[STATUS] = (-1)

from    @stats_table as [stats]

    inner join [LINKED INSTANCE].[DATABASE].[dbo].[LINKEDTABLE] as [source]
    on [source].[INDEX] = [stats].[Index]
```

This is resulting in the trigger on the remote end (target) firing once per row updated rather than at an statement level. In the above example the trigger fires 4 times, however the statement below only fires once.

```
update  [source]
set     [source].[STATUS] = (-1)

from    [LINKED INSTANCE].[DATABASE].[dbo].[LINKEDTABLE] as [source]
where [source].[INDEX] in(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Is there anyone able to explain where I'm going wrong. Is there a configuration setting or something that I'm missing ?

Regards,

Tim

Comment: how do you check that how many times a trigger is fired ?

Comment: The trigger simply inserts a row into a table as a test. If the trigger fires once then I'll have one row in the table. I'm truncating this table before I run these tests. I've always assumed triggers fire at a statement level, but this doesn't appear to be the case when using a linked query update across multiple instances on the same box. Strange ... Very strange.